# Oracle query issue using concat || operator

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am trying to query a string as follows.

Currently my Oracle table has around 60 columns. So to query a string for against all columns will be as follows,

**Working query:**

```
select * from <table_name> where (col1||col2||col3...||col60) like '%string%'
```

**Not working query:**

I have added one more query to get all columns dynamically as below,

```
select * from <table_name> where (select LISTAGG(COLUMN_NAME, '||') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME) from all_tab_columns where TABLE_NAME = '<table_name>' and OWNER = '<owner_name>' and DATA_TYPE != 'CLOB') like '%string%'
```

**sub query :**

There is no issue with the below subquery.

```
select LISTAGG(COLUMN_NAME, '||') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME) from all_tab_columns where TABLE_NAME = '<table_name>' and OWNER = '<owner_name>' and DATA_TYPE != 'CLOB'
```

Where the subquery is returning output like in the working query.

I am thinking that the oracle taking the "||" concat operator only when it is hardcoding it.

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: This is never called the "pipe" operator in SQL.  That is only in unix shell script.

Comment: You have to use ***dynamic SQL*** to achieve your desired result.  The col1||col2 in your first query are taking the VALUES in the columns and combining them.  Your second query is combining the COLUMN names, not the values, to compare to %string%.  So your second query is basically returning the string 'Col1||Col2||Col3...' and comparing it to %string%.   This is vastly different than the 1st  query.  To achieve what I think you're after, you would have to make the 2nd query a string concatenating the results of the sub query and then `execute (str)`;

Comment: Note that your 'working' query probably gets a mismatch if `Col2` ends `st` and `Col3` starts `ring`.  You'll have to decide whether that's a problem or not.

Comment: If you need to do something like that, this might indicate a wrong design. Maybe you should re-think your database model. Or you could consider a computed column that concatenates all columns and then you only need to query a single column. Or think about using Oracle's full text search capabilities

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would solve your problem in a way that would scale.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW COLUMN_SEARCH AS

SELECT ID, COL1 AS COL
FROM TABLENAME

UNION ALL

SELECT ID, COL2 AS COL
FROM TABLENAME

UNION ALL

SELECT ID, COL3 AS COL
FROM TABLENAME

UNION ALL

SELECT ID, COL4 AS COL
FROM TABLENAME

UNION ALL

--- 

SELECT ID, COLN AS COL
FROM TABLENAME
```

Now with this view your query is just

```
SELECT TABLENAME.*
FROM TABLENAME
JOIN COLUMN_SEARCH ON TABLENAME.ID = COLUMN_SEARCH.ID
WHERE COLUMN_SEARCH.COL = 'string'
```

If you need this to be dynamic then just update view everytime there is a new column added.

If it is running slow then just make an index on ID, COL in the view.

---

**Update based on comments**

I want to add a some comments about using dynamic SQL to solve this problem.  You can use dynamic SQL to solve this problem but it would be a bad idea.  (*For those that don't know -- creating the query dynamically from meta data about the columns everytime you run the query would be using dynamic SQL*)

Here is why I don't recommend it:

1. **Dynamic SQL is really hard to maintain** -- it is (by definition) more complicated than non dynamic SQL and it never looks very much the query you are really trying to run.  While it seems like it would make maintenance easier "Everytime I add a column it just automatically adds in in - bim-bamb-boom!"  In fact, I've found everytime you add a column it is better to make a choice "Do I want to add this in."  Sometimes it helps to automatically add it but many times it will break the system.
2. **Dynamic SQL breaks optimization** -- SQL platforms have decades of optimization built into their compilers, they do an amazing job.  Because dynamic SQL can't be per-compiled and cached you lose a lot on performance in addition to the time it takes to create the dynamic SQL.
3. **Dynamic SQL can't easily be tweaked and tuned** -- A lot of what a DBA does is look at how data models are being used and then add indexes, partitions, materialized queries and other tuning to make the system run quickly.  It is much harder to do this kind of tuning on dynamic SQL (but not impossible).
4. **Dynamic SQL is a bad code smell** -- This is more subtle *and may not apply to this particular question* but needs to be said -- if you are using dynamic sql it is probably an indication you did something wrong with your data model or you are using the wrong tool.  There are a number of "nosql" systems out there that might be better suited for solving your particular data issue.

Comment: Yes, I agree, But when i apply that into query "Where" condition, it is giving empty result set.

Comment: that's because the string 'col1||col2||col3' is not the same as the literals `col1||col2||Col3` in which the values of col1, col2, and col3 would be combined to form 1 value. which is then compared to %string%.

Comment: @Yadheendran let me re-write to actually solve your problem.

Comment: This will produce multiple copies of the same row if the same string is present in more than one column in the same row. And the view still needs hard-coding of the column names, which was the OP's problem in the first place. I don't see how this will help him.

Comment: @mathguy as you know a distinct can solve the multi-row issue.  This will help him because it shows the correct way to architect a solution to the problem given the data model he has.  It is in my opinion given what he has told us and with 25+ years experience the best way (best in terms of maintainability and speed) to solve this problem.  If you have a better one please post an answer -- I'd love to learn something new.

Comment: The more serious remark about your solution is that it doesn't allow "to get all columns dynamically" any more than the OP's attempt. I don't see anything in your answer that addresses that. (You probably know, with 25+ years of experience, that there is NO possible way to get the columns dynamically in plain SQL.) For full disclosure - you can safely disregard everything I say, I am an amateur who has been learning Oracle for less than a year and with zero practical experience, I do all my testing on my computer at home. I am retired from a 100% non-IT career.

Comment: @mathguy - I don't understand why you say my I don't address this dynamic issue.   **I address this issue right in my answer** I say: the view should be updated when the data model is updated.  This should not happen often and can be scripted if needed.  If that happens a lot then it is clear the user has a bad data model but even so whatever "system" is adding columns can also add to the view.

Comment: Dynamically = at runtime. Agreed? (If not, we are not using the same vocabulary, so attempts to communicate will fail.) Dynamic SQL (see link below) is required if the columns are not known when the query is written. As in: looking for the string in any column in any of 100 tables; the query should be the same for all tables, with the columns changing from one call to the next. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#LNPLS011

Comment: @mathguy -- Please see the edit to my answer.  If that does not convince you then I'll be happy to agree to disagree with you.

Comment: @mathguy -- this was my point in #4 -- if you have a system that is looking for a string in any column of 100 tables then you should not be using a relational SQL based solution.    In addition if you had to do so (eg legacy system) any dynamic SQL solution would be way to slow at scale.

Comment: I completely, 100% agree with your added comments. The OP shouldn't do what he is trying to do.